# Default Identity Provider attribute value

Tags: keycloak

Currently having a business requirement where we have to default First and Last name in the event they are returned null from Identity Provider. In the current scenario, Keycloak displays a form that appears after the Identity Provider call is completed - it should not appear in this case.

Firstname is not that common, but the Lastname is not a mandatory field on e.g. Google account.

Is there a way to default Lastname to "Doe" if the value is null? e.g. via a Mapper rule?

Comment: You want to have the default to avoid keycloak asking for those fields when you do identity Brokering ?

Comment: @dreamcrash, exactly. I understand that the request is a little bit "weird" but it is a business use case.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at your custom authentication flow and select that flow during first browser login. I would have to look into in more detail to see if that is possible.